# Gradle "There is no feature named VERSION_CATALOGS"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to upgrade Gradle version from 7.x to 8.x. However, when I completed my Gradle wrapper upgrade and ran the project I encountered the following error:

> Settings file '.../settings.gradle.kts' line: 7
>
> There is no feature named VERSION_CATALOGS

Here is how my `settings.gradle.kts` looks like:

```kotlin
include(
    ":project-a",  
    ":project-b",  
)

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")  
    versionCatalogs {  
        create("libs") {  
            val kotlinVersion = "1.8.10"  
            val dokkaVersion = "1.8.10"
            
            plugin("jetbrains-kotlin-jvm", "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version(kotlinVersion)  
            plugin("jetbrains-dokka", "org.jetbrains.dokka").version(dokkaVersion)  
        }  
    }
}
```

When I checked the release notes, there was no mention of this, has it been fully de-incubated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `versionCatalogs` block was promoted to a stable feature [since 7.4 RC1](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/19435). However, the inactive feature preview was [removed in v8.0.0-M1](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/29bbb70e78e70d235053ca5e4a38b0f9bcfe4cce). (I assume a lot of users who have forgotten to remove it early will encounter this error on upgrade)

So you can safely ignore this error, and remove line number 7. (i.e. `enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")`)

Other helpful resources:

- [Gradle 8.0 Release Notes](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/release-notes.html#promoted-features)
- [Upgrading your build from Gradle 7.x to 8.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html)